# How to establish a multiple clients - single server architecture using SSH reverse port forwarding

Tags: ssh, network-programming, client-server, nat, ssh-tunnel

I am working on a project consisting of the **bidirectionnal (and secure) connexion of a lot of Raspberry PI** -**N clients**- to a known, accessible, **fixed-IP adress Server**.

The clients (Raspberry PI) are all connected to the Internet via a classic NAT. Let say **clients are identified by a number between 1 and N.**

```
[Client] Raspberry PI <-> NAT (Internet Provider) <-> Internet
All client's public IP are dynamic
```

The **Server** is located somewhere on the Internet at the **IP address A**

--- **My** **GOAL** : Connect each client to the server with the **SSH** **protocol**. ---

The **Server** needs to **send data at will to any client** (no broadcast), and each client needs to send data to the server.

**There will be "N" SSH tunnels**, initiated by the clients , using reverse-port forwarding or/and port forwarding.

That's where i lack knowledge in SSH:

> 1) **How can the server associate each tunnels with a client** in
>   order to be able to use the proper tunnel ? How can a program (for
>   example in C) identify and "use" each tunnel for sending and receving
>   server-side?
>
> 2) **Using [reverse] port forwarding, what are the needs in ports
>   server side, does each clients needs a remote port on the server?**
>
> 3) **Do i need to create a program that link each outgoing port to a
>   client ID** and same thing for ingoing port?

My problem is when the server needs to send data to a specific client, **how to do it ?**

Thank you very much.